# cmdlet Get-FileHash works in powershell but is not recognized in command prompt

Tags: powershell, cmd

When i execute these commands in PowerShell it executes correctly

```
Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml
Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml | Out-File HashResult.log
```

When i use the same command in command prompt it doesn't execute

```
powershell -command "& {&'Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml'}"
powershell -command "& {&'Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml | Out-File HashResult.log'}"
```

It gives the following error:

> The term 'Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml' is not recognized
>   as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
>   Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
>   the path is correct and try again.

Basic cmdlets like these do work in powershell and command prompt

Powershell:

```
Get-NetIPConfiguration
```

CMD:

```
powershell -command "& {&'Get-NetIPConfiguration'}"
```

Any explanation or any suggestions on how to make the first commands work are welcome.

Comment: remove the & ' so just: `powershell -command "& {Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml}"`

Comment: Yes that works, thank you. Can you explain why it wouldn't work with the "&"  but it does work with the "&" in the basic cmdlet?

Comment: Why use `cmd.exe` at all? Run the commands in PowerShell.

Comment: I made an extention that executes the command so people can double click it without worrying how it works.

Comment: Why? Quoting makes it one single object (instead of four: one cmdlet, one switch and two parameters). So the errormessage is right - there is no cmdlet named `Get-FileHash -Algorithm SHA256 file.xml`